# Fetch the data from sqlite database with multiple columns and rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

[image: This is result of that query]

I am creating an app for iPhone in which I am using sqlite to create a database. I wrote a query in which it returns 4 columns with multiple rows.

First column have values like indian territory(NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST), in Second column it have the states name which belongs to these territory. There is almost 4 states in each territory. It may increase after some time. Third and fourth column have some no data which is belong to that state. How to show If I clicked in south territory then it should show all the south states in tableview. How to match the state names with its territory and fetch data according to that.

Now I have to add all states according to territory, please not give me static code like Territory= INDIA EAST, because if territory increases than it will fail.

I have to add all states into different arrays according to its region like all south in one array and all north in one array and so on..

Comment: so where is the query?

Comment: show us the code of what you tried

Answer (score 1):

We could use a look at your schema, but a query like this sounds like it would work:

```
select states from my_table where territory = 'NORTH'
```

You can run sqlite3 from Terminal and execute queries there, which will help you concoct your queries. Also I suggest looking at FMDB, which offers a nice API to help interface your code to SQLite. It has excellent documentation which will help translate your query's results into ObjC/Swift data structures.

Comment: im glad that you suggested FMDB